# Is there a 64 bit TclPro?

Tags: load, shared-libraries, tcl, 32bit-64bit

I am trying to install [TclPro1.4](http://www.tcl.tk/software/tclpro/eval/1.4.html) on 64 bit host.

Here is what `uname -a` returns:

```
Linux hp1 2.6.18-194.11.1.el5 #1 SMP Tue Aug 10 19:05:06 EDT 2010 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I have installed TclPro1.4 from corresponding iso disk image (it is available by the link mentioned above), but it installed 32 bit libraries instead of 64 bit ones (located at /opt/ajuba/TclPro1.4/linux-ix86/lib/).

So in this situation seems there is no way for TclPro to wrap an application which uses 64 bit .so files. When trying to do so, I am getting error messages when trying to load that 64 bit .so file:

```
couldn't load file "libsome64bit.so": libsome64bit.so: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64
```

So the questions are: is there a way to install a 64 bit TclPro on 64 bit host? If no, is there a way to make 32 bit TclPro to work with 64 bit .so files?

Is there a way to download TclPro source files and build them locally to obtain 64 bit TclPro?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TclPro is deprecated. You need to use [TDK](http://www.activestate.com/tcl-dev-kit) (ActiveState Tcl Development Kit)

You've 64 bits Linux support.

Comment: Is there a free version (or alternative) of TDK?

Comment: @Vahagn AFAIK no. Anyway, do you really need to bytecode your scripts?